# SQL ADODB Recordset select distinct is in alphabetical order

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

I'm using an ADODB record set in VBA. When I use Select Distinct in a SQL query of the ADODB record set the results come out in alphabetical order. I need the results in the order they are in the data. Is that possible?

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

DatPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp\" & TB.Name

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DatPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT Distinct(Period) from [Data$] "


rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ADO Out").Cells.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ADO Out").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ADO Out").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: Is there a column (besides row number) that has this ordering?

Comment: @Hogan I'm afraid not. I've tried without success to get the row number too.

Comment: can you modify the excel file?  If so add a column with `=ROW()` and then sort by that column.

Comment: I can do, but I was hoping for a simpler solution using SQL. :-(

Comment: As far as SQL is concerned, order is what you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two workarounds that both involve retrieving all `Period` records.

### `Range.RemoveDuplicates` will remove the duplicates while preserving the order

```
Sub UnorderedPeriod()
    Dim DatPath As String, strCon As String, strSQL As String
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    DatPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp\" & TB.Name

    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DatPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    cn.Open strCon

    strSQL = "SELECT [Period] from [Data$]"


    rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ADO Out")
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
        .Activate
        .Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
    End With

End Sub
```

### Use an `ArrayList` to remove the duplicates

```
Function CopyDistinctFromRecordset(rs As Object, Target As Range)
    Dim list As Object
    Dim data
    Dim x As Long
    rs.MoveFirst
    data = rs.getRows
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For x = 0 To UBound(data, 2)
        If Not list.Contains(data(0, x)) Then list.Add data(0, x)
    Next

    Target.Resize(list.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(list.ToArray)

End Function
```